# FreeTds inside Docker throwing unknown symbol exception

Tags: c++, docker, cgi, freetds

I'm trying to run a CGI website in a docker.
The software is written in c++ and uses to FreeTDS-dev package to connect to a mssql database.
so far its working as it should the only problem is:
If I try to compile or run it inside of the docker I receive
the following exception:

```
undefined symbol: dbprcollen
```

now I know where the exact line of code is and I also know that this particular function should be inside the freetds-dev package.
So I've included this package into the dockerfile
but it still won't work. Does Anyone know what I am missing?

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM php:apache

COPY ./html/ /var/www/html/
COPY ./work.cgi /var/www/html/work.cgi

RUN chmod +x /var/www/html/work.cgi
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN echo "<Directory /var/www/html/>\n\
        AllowOverride all\n\
        Options +ExecCGI\n\
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi\n\
</Directory>" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/cgi.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/cgi.load

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install build-essential -y
RUN apt install binutils -y
RUN apt install libcgicc-dev -y
RUN apt install freetds-bin -y
RUN apt install freetds-dev -y
RUN apt update --fix-missing -y
RUN apt upgrade -y
```

Comment: Please provide entire dockerfile.

Comment: @mchawre this is the entire dockerfile